# Trouble with pip install twilio

Tags: python, pip, twilio

When I try to use pip install twilio, I get this message:

```
"DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support"
```

I've gone around in circles trying everything, any tips?
When I type python --version in the terminal, I get Python 3.8.2

Comment: Never use the `pip` script directly (or `pip3` or anything like that). Instead always prefer the more surefire explicit way by calling _pip_'s _executable module_ for a specific _Python_ interpreter: `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip somecommand` -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install twilio
```

Assuming you have python3 installed, and the pip for python3 should be pip3.

Comment: When running that I get WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: After updating, I get DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (20.0.2)

Comment: ... so what do you want? A python 2 or python 3 to install twilio?

Comment: I believe python3, however I think that my mac is still linked to python 2.7, rather than 3.8. The end goal is to import things from Twilio in python files.